# how to add all titles to the queue of handbrake automatically?

Tags: handbrake

When I open a DVD in Handbrake, it's scanned and the main title is found by the tool. The output name is also automatically adjusted. Then I may add it to the queue. But I need all titles to be added to the queue automatically with proper names specifying their title number. While now, I need to name them and select from the title combobox and add them one after another.
I didn't find Handbrake forum. So I decided to ask here.

Comment: Titles can't be added automatically jn Handbrake.

Comment: where can i find developers and suggest this to them?

Comment: https://handbrake.fr/community.php

Comment: thank u very much
please change the comment to answer so that i may accept it.

Comment: I rather not because a question about a feature of a multi-platform software has nothing to do with Ubuntu therefore off-topic.

Comment: If the software runs on Ubuntu, in general asking about it is on-topic (@CelticWarrior) but bug reports and feature requests should go to the developers; they are off-topic here

Comment: @Zanna Exactly. Things are rarely black&white therefore I tend to consider whether or not the issue is Ubuntu specific (it's not).

Comment: @CelticWarrior sorry to keep rambling on, but I need to speak my mind - things that are not Ubuntu-specific are usually still on-topic if they work on Ubuntu (see for example thousands of command line questions). I think I am actually quite strict relative to the community in general and err on the side of close-if-we're-not-sure, but if something works on all Linux distros or even on Linux Mac and Windows, that doesn't make asking about running it on Ubuntu off-topic. I'm sure you know this, but I seem to have been called with `-vvv` this morning

Comment: @Zanna - You're most welcome. The issue here is about the suggested change of my comment above to an answer. I declined because one way or another the question is off-topic and I don't post answers in off-topic questions. I can help by giving suggestions or point to one direction or another, in comments. That's all anyone should do, at most, in such cases. Perhaps I should have been more explicit and said ¨ feature request¨.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this automatically, but if Simultaneously would serve, Here's an excerpt from the [Handbrake Team Documentation](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/advanced/queue.html)

**Adding multiple encodes simultaneously**

When using the Queue, you may find it beneficial to create multiple Jobs at one time.

If your Source is a Blu-ray, DVD, or other disc or disc-like format with multiple Titles, you may open it with HandBrake and add multiple Titles to the Queue simultaneously.

Additionally, you may open a folder of multiple single-Title videos (excluding discs and disc-like formats) as one virtual Source with multiple Titles using the Open Source dialog, and then add multiple Titles to the Queue.

On Linux, select Add Multiple from the Queue menu, then select the Titles you wish to encode using the presented dialog. Be sure to give each a unique file name.

You may open additional Sources and add them to the Queue in the same manner.

**EDIT:**

As an alternative you could script write a script that loops through all the files in a given directory and run the same conversion command on all of them utilizing [handbrake-cli](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=handbrake-cli&searchon=names)

Comment: This answer can be updated with the answer from Mark.

Answer (score 3):

If you right-click on the "Add to Queue" button, you will see an option called "Show 'Add All' to Queue".

Click that and you'll get a new button called "Add All". Clicking on that will add all of the titles to your encoding queue.

[image]

Be sure to tick Preferences -> General -> 'Automatically name output files' so the files don't overwrite each other!

Check also the *automatic file renaming* format. By default it should be `{source}-{title}` (more information in the [documentation](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/technical/automatic-file-naming.html)). Adapt it to your source to get unique file name for each file.